# Out, Among or From?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions, word-meaning

What is the difference among these 3 words?

> He had to choose which I liked best **from/ among/ out of** 10 ice creams.
>
> I chose this tie **out of/ from/ among** my 6 (ties).
>
> There were many things to choose **from/ among/ from among/ out of**

Comment: Hi Jason, have you tried consulting a dictionary, or looking for an answer online?